# Change the value of a select box option using another select box whose values are different

Tags: javascript

I have two select boxes with different values. I want to be able to select an option on either box and change the value in the other so they correspond. For example, if I select '2 people' from the '#numberofpeople' selection, I want the '#apartment' select box to show '2 bed apartment'. And vice versa. Here is my form code -

```
<form>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right"><label><span style="color:#CC0000;"> * </span>Number Of People :</label></td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
          <span style="text-align: left"></span>
          <div class="styledselectAlt"><select name="numberofpeople" id="numberofpeople">
            <option value="000" selected="selected"></option>              
            <option value="1 person" <?php if ( $numberofpeople == 1 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>1</option>
            <option value="2 people" <?php if ( $numberofpeople == 2 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>2</option>
            <option value="3 people" <?php if ( $numberofpeople == 3 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>3</option>
            <option value="4 people" <?php if ( $numberofpeople == 4 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>4</option>
            <option value="5 people" <?php if ( $numberofpeople == 5 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>5</option>
            <option value="6 people" <?php if ( $numberofpeople == 6 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>6</option>
          </select></div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right; color: #7b7b7b;"><label for="apartment"><span style="color:#CC0000;"> * </span>Apartment Size :</label></td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
          <span style="text-align: left"></span>
          <div class="styledselect"><select name="apartment" id="apartment">
            <option value="1 Bed Apartment" <?php if ( $apartment == "1 Bed Apartment" ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>1 Bed Apartment</option>
            <option value="2 Bed Apartment" <?php if ( $apartment == "2 Bed Apartment" ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>2 Bed Apartment</option>
            <option value="3 Bed Apartment" <?php if ( $apartment == "3 Bed Apartment" ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>3 Bed Apartment</option>
            <option value="4 Bed Apartment" <?php if ( $apartment == "4 Bed Apartment" ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>4 Bed Apartment</option>
            <option value="3 Bed & 2 Bed Apartment" <?php if ( $apartment == "3 Bed & 2 Bed Apartment" ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>3 Bed & 2 Bed Apartment</option>
            <option value="4 Bed & 2 Bed Apartment" <?php if ( $apartment == "4 Bed & 2 Bed Apartment" ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>4 Bed & 2 Bed Apartment</option>
          </select></div>
        </td>
      </tr>

</form>
```

Below is the Javascript snippet, I've used, that does the job if the corresponding values of the select boxes are the same. I've tried to manipulate the code, but to no avail. Suggestions/solutions will be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var s1=document.getElementById('numberofpeople');
 var s2=document.getElementById('apartment');
      s1.onchange=function(){
          s2.value=s1.value;
      }
      s2.onchange=function(){
          s1.value=s2.value;
      }

</script>
```

Comment: You should code the `value` attributes accordingly to match, or use a custom `data` attribute to match. Else, I suppose you can have a giant chain of `if else` statements, but that'll get ugly.

Comment: YO!!!! - Thank you, you've hit the nail on the head

Answer (score 0):

You can change many things to solve.
The most important error is the value of the selects. You have different values so they won't never be the same

Here is the solution:

```
<tr>
        <td style="text-align: right"><label><span style="color:#CC0000;"> * </span>Number Of People :</label></td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <span style="text-align: left"></span>
            <div class="styledselectAlt"><select name="numberofpeople" id="numberofpeople">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>              
                    <option value="1" >1</option>
                    <option value="2" >2</option>
                    <option value="3" >3</option>
                    <option value="4" >4</option>
                    <option value="5" >5</option>
                    <option value="6" >6</option>
                </select></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right; color: #7b7b7b;"><label for="apartment"><span style="color:#CC0000;"> * </span>Apartment Size :</label></td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <span style="text-align: left"></span>
            <div class="styledselect"><select name="apartment" id="apartment">
                    <option value="1" >1 Bed Apartment</option>
                    <option value="2">2 Bed Apartment</option>
                    <option value="3" >3 Bed Apartment</option>
                    <option value="4" >4 Bed Apartment</option>
                    <option value="5">3 Bed & 2 Bed Apartment</option>
                    <option value="6">4 Bed & 2 Bed Apartment</option>
                </select></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Or you can change the javascript and work with the index:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var s1 = document.getElementById('numberofpeople');
    var s2 = document.getElementById('apartment');
    s1.onchange = function() {
         s2.selectedIndex = s1.selectedIndex
    }
    s2.onchange = function() {
         s1.selectedIndex = s2.selectedIndex;
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Thank you - as you can see I'm spoilt for choice!!! Looking forward to posting my next query

Answer (score 0):

Using your current HTML you can do something like this:

```
var fn = function (a) {
    return function () {
        var v1 = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value.split(' ')[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < a.options.length; i++) {
            if (v1 === a[i].value.split(' ')[0]) {
                a.selectedIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

var s1 = document.getElementById('numberofpeople');
var s2 = document.getElementById('apartment');
s1.onchange = fn(s2);
s2.onchange = fn(s1);
```

[**See this working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jMscY/)